# spring-amqp will not insert message using AmqpTemplate.convertAndSend()

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

Here is a small Spring program that is expected to insert a message into a rabbitmq queue:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(QueueConfiguration.class);
    AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
    template.convertAndSend("asdflk ...");
    context.destroy();
  }
}
```

The ApplicationContext is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class QueueConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory("192.168.1.39");
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
  }
}
```

When I check the contents of the queues on the server, nothing gets inserted. I also tried to set the name of the exchange or the name of the queue on the RabbitTemplate, but still nothing shows up on the server.

The log of the application does not show any errors, but logs this:

```
17:28:02.441 [main] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@192.168.1.39:5672/,1)
17:28:02.441 [main] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Publishing message on exchange [], routingKey = []
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to give the queue as a parameter in the call to convertAndSend():

```
template.convertAndSend("hello2", "asdflk ...");
```

Still wondering why spring-amqp would not throw an exception. Anybody knows where the messages are delivered when no queue is given?

Comment: That's just the way amqp/rabbitmq works - unroutable messages are silently dropped by default. Note that routing by queue name is a convenience because all queues are bound to the default exchange with a routing key equal to the queue name. It is generally advised to decouple the producer from the queue by binding the queue to an exchange with a routing key.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will keep the Routing Key and Queue name in the bean `rabbitTemplate()` as per [spring-amqp example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/blob/master/helloworld/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/helloworld/HelloWorldConfiguration.java). Since I am working with multiple queues currently I have different class for each queue in which I have the rabbitTemplate like this:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    //The routing key = name of the queue in default exchange.
    template.setRoutingKey("MyQueue");
    // Queue name
    template.setQueue("MyQueue");
    return template;
}
```

Are you using tomcat to deploy this? If yes then these can be loaded at startup which will initialize all the connection/channel/queues etc as well.